# Test Class is not getting covered Messaging.SingleEmailMessage in batch class

Tags: unit-test, batch

Test Class is not getting covered for singleemailmessage.

**Part of Code :**

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List < Contract > recs) {
                List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > mailList = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > ();
                for (Contract c: recs) {
                    if (c.Contact_Email__c != null) {
                        List < String > toAddresses = new List < String > ();
                        List < String > CcAddresses = new List < String > ();
                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                       ccAddresses.add(c.Account.Owner.Email);
                         mail.setCcAddresses(CcAddresses);
                          mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Contact__r.ID);
                          mail.setWhatId(c.Id);
                          mail.setTemplateId('00X4B000000M08W');
                          mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                        mailList.add(mail);
                    }
                }

              Messaging.sendEmail(mailList);

            }
```

Test Class :

```
@isTest
public class TestNinetyDaysNotificationEmail{
static testMethod void TestNinetyDays()
{
Account acc90 = new Account(Name='Testing NinetyDaysNotificationEmail' );
        insert acc90 ;
contact cc90 = new contact(FirstName ='Test Contact', LastName ='NinetyDaysNotificationEmail', Role__c='Subscription Administrator',Email='xyz@edb.com',AccountId=acc90.Id);
        insert cc90;

        Opportunity opty90 = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test Oppty NinetyDaysNotificationEmail', StageName ='Proposal/Price Quote', CloseDate = System.Today(),  AccountId = acc90.Id,);
        insert opty90;

        list<OpportunityContactRole> opptyConRolelist90 =  new list<OpportunityContactRole>{
            new OpportunityContactRole(ContactId = cc90.Id, OpportunityId = opty90.Id, IsPrimary = false, Role = 'Subscription Administrator')
        };   
        insert opptyConRolelist90;

product2 p90 = new product2(Name='PostgresPlus',Product_Name1__C='Product - Subscription',IsActive = true, Renewable__c=True);
        insert p90;

        PricebookEntry pbey90 = new PricebookEntry(Product2ID=p90.id, Pricebook2ID= test.getStandardPricebookId(), UnitPrice=50, isActive=true);
        insert pbey90;

        Opportunitylineitem ooli9 = new Opportunitylineitem(OpportunityId = opty90.Id, PricebookEntryId = pbey90.Id, Quantity =4, Start_Date__c = System.today(), End_Date__c =  System.today() + 90); 
  insert ooli9;

        Opportunitylineitem ooli90 = new Opportunitylineitem(OpportunityId = opty90.Id, PricebookEntryId = pbey90.Id, Quantity =4, Start_Date__c = System.today(), End_Date__c =  System.today() + 100,  Parent_Opportunity_Product_Id__c=ooli9.Id);
        insert ooli90;

         Contract contr90 = new Contract(CurrencyIsoCode='USD',   Opportunity_Product_Id__c=ooli9.Id,AccountId=acc90.Id,StartDate=System.today() ,EndDate=System.today()+90);
        insert contr90;

Contract_Role__c contrRole90 = new Contract_Role__c(Role__c='Subscription Administrator' ,Contract__c=contr90.Id);
        insert contrRole90;

        Test.StartTest();
        NinetyDaysNotificationEmail Ninetydays = new NinetyDaysNotificationEmail();
        Database.executebatch(Ninetydays);
        Test.StopTest();
    }   
     Static testMethod void TestNinetyDays90()
    { 
        Test.StartTest();
        NinetyDaysNotificationEmail AE = new  NinetyDaysNotificationEmail();
        String sch = '0 0 23 * * ?'; 
        system.schedule('Test Notification email to Customer', sch, AE); 
        //Database.executebatch(b);
        Test.StopTest();
    }
    }
```

Comment: what does the batch start() method and query look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your single email message code will get covered only if your contract have contact email field not null.

But in your test class, while creating contract you didn't set that field.

Edit:

As per discussion in comments, the contact_email__c field is a formula which contains the Email of a custom Contact relationship field in Contract. So you need to populate that relationship field and your formula will work. Add `contact__c = cc90.Id` to the contract creation code as

```
Contract contr90 = new Contract(CurrencyIsoCode='USD', Opportunity_Product_Id__c=ooli9.Id,AccountId=acc90.Id,StartDate=System.today() ,EndDate=System.today()+90,contact__c = cc90.Id);
insert contr90;
```

Note:

cc90 is the contact you have inserted in your test class which i got from your question.

Hope it helps.

Comment: :Thanks for your response.Contact_email__c is a formula field.How do i get that field .Any suggestion please.

Comment: Can you add the formula code to your question so that we can take a look and provide suggestions.

Comment: :Contact which has a loopup relation to Contract as Contact__c and the formula field is given as Contact_Email__c =Contact__r.Email .

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @ Vigneshwaran G :As suggested ,i have added it ,but their is no change in the code coverage it shows only 53%.Any suggestion please.

Comment: :I had another formula field in product ,i have update it now the code coverage got increased to 100%.Thanks for your time and needful help.